# Magento Order Mangement Confusion? No invoice automatically created?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

I am a bit confused about how the orders works. I am using a national third-party service for Payment. Let's just call them, PaymentCompany.

Let me take you through an order.

Frontend
1. Customer chooses an product, add to cart and go to checkout.
2. Customer chooses shipping method and payment method which will be through PaymentCompany. 
3. Customer get 'thank you'-page and leaves the website.
4. Customer also gets notified per email that an order was placed.

Backend
1. In sales->orders there is now placed an order as "processing". 
2. If I now go to the order and click "invoice", there is none. Which means I have to click and create an invoice. This will again notify the customer with an Invoice. 
3. Click shipment, which will notify the customer that it is shipped.

My questions: 
1. Why is the Invoice not automatically created? 
2. If it is so, that that's just how it works, why do the customer get notified when I create the invoice?

Comment: That is just how Magento works. You can disable any or all of the customer email notifications in the admin.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this website for paypal setup 
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout-intro.html#step1

goto System->Configuration->Payment Mehthod ->Paypal Express

Search for  Basic Settings - PayPal Payments Pro
and set Payment Method to sale